# Underscore - safely get property after _.find

Tags: underscore.js

As the title says, I'm trying to get property of object after find, safely.

Let's assume, that I have such array:

```
var ppl = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Smith' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Wesson' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Remington' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Colt' }
];
```

So I'm trying to get a name of one of this respectful gentlemans by id, so I'm using `_.find`.

```
var person = _.find(ppl, function(p) { return p.id === 2; });
```

I'm looking for a way to safely get `name` in the `_` chain. Something like:

```
var personName = _.chain(ppl)
                  .find(function(p) { return p.id === 2; })
                  .get('name') //<-- can't find appropriate method :(
                  .values();
```

Ofc I can do it with checks like if(person && person.name)... Or even write my own prototype method, but don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [GruffBunny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39527285/3689450) is correct in that you seem to be using Lodash, rather than Underscore. I also find like the solution provided in that answer to be quite elegant, but I wanted to show an alternative.

Note: I will provide an Underscore answer, since the question is tagged as such but also a Lodash one, since OP seems to be interested in that

## Underscore.js

One thing that I always found a bit awkward is the exact situation you're in - chain (an array) -> do operations -> find -> do other things. The Object functions in Underscore are slightly off. However, we can still try to do it:

```js
var ppl = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Smith' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Wesson' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Remington' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Colt' }
];

function findName(id) {
  return _.chain(ppl)
  .findWhere({id: id}) // <- shorter syntax than _.find and does the same as supplying your own function. 
                      // It's even shorter than the already short fat arrow syntax which would be: (p => p.id === 2)
  .pick('name') // <- extract a new object that has a single property "name"
  .map() //<- 1. for objects, it's equivalent to mapping the values only, e.g., _.map(_.values(obj)) 
         //^- 2. if no argument is specified, it defaults to _.identity
  .first() // <- since the previous step returns an array of one value this step unwraps it and leaves you with a plain value
  .value(); // end chain, return result
}

console.log("Find ID = 2:", findName(2));
console.log("Find ID = 42:", findName(42));
console.log('Find ID = "2" (string value):', findName("2"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

So, this will do the job but it is a bit awkward. You're lacking the `.get`, so you have to pluck -> map -> first to do the equivalent. It's not strictly bad_ but it's not-as-good as it could. One alternative is to keep your single result in an array which will allow you to run additional functions. So, you can do this

```
_.chain(ppl)
  .where({id: id}) //it's basically "filterWhere" like _.findWhere but it returns all results in an array. In this case, it would be a single result purely so we can do the below
  .map('name') //<- allows you to map by name of the property but only with arrays
  .first() // <- still have to unwrap
  .value();
```

let's see the equivalent

## Lodash

Lodash is a bit better, since it has a bit smoother syntax and also has a bit better handling of objects, so you don't face situations where you have to keep them in an array of one value.

```js
var ppl = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Smith' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Wesson' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Remington' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Colt' }
];

function findName(id, defaultName) {
  return _.chain(ppl)
  .find({id: id}) //<- Lodash does not have _.findWhere but the normal _.find already handles this
  .get('name') // <- see, much simpler! You can also supply a second argument which would be returned as a default value
  .value();
}

console.log("Find ID = 2:", findName(2));
console.log("Find ID = 42:", findName(42));
console.log('Find ID = "2" (string value):', findName("2"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great! Thx. I'm using underscore with angular ui-router, so trying to use it to max potential.

Comment: I'm glad I could help then. I will leave the Lodash solution just to show the difference between the approaches.

Answer (score 2):

As you're using `get` I'm assuming that you're using lodash and not underscore. If so then you could use [**defaultTo**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#defaultTo) which was introduced in version 4.14.0:

```js
var ppl = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Smith' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Wesson' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Remington' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Colt' }
];

var nullPerson = {
  id: 0, 
  name: 'null'
}

var personName = _.chain(ppl)
  .find({id: 99})
  .defaultTo(nullPerson)
  .get('name')
  .value();

console.log(personName);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I like that. I didn't know about `defaultTo`.

Comment: I'm using Underscore, as you can see in the title. I just mentioned, how I see the solution, but underscore doesn't have such method.